# Hide DIV background-image without rest of content

Tags: html, css

so my use case is that I have a div with a big background image and some other divs with text inside. In my css file I have a media query for max-width, so that below that width the image should disappear.

I have tried both visibility:hidden and background-image:none, but in both cases the text also disappears.

Is there a way to not make the other divs disappear? Or an alternative way to construct this structure to accomplish the goal stated above?

HTML:

```
<div id="teaser">
    <span id="teaser-text"> Text </span>
    <div id="attributes">   Some Text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#teaser {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 66.44%;
    background-image: url('/static/main/freude2_bright1.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Show your div code and show your css please.

Comment: If you want something to only show when  a size is bigger than .... You need to use min-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is #teaser on a white background? If so, you're text may not be disappearing, but could be white on white after you've removed the image.

Try:

```
@media all and (max-width:480px) {
  #teaser {
    background-image: none;
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to remove the background image (or maybe color?) of a div but not effect the other content within it?

```
.main-div {
  background-color: none;
  background-image: none;
}
```